# Efficient way to remove items from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two dictionaries dict1 and dict2, I would like to remove items from dict1 which are present in dict2 using its key. Instead of looping through dict2 and using "ContainsKey" method, ia there any other approach like using linq.

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: Linq will do the same as a loop would it just hides it. using Linq would only be for brevity

Comment: The method you have described (a loop with `ContiansKey`) is the best method.

Comment: @CuongLe Why would it matter?  I can't think of any cases where the type of the key would change the answer.

Comment: I like Servy's approach but...if you really just had to use Linq and absolutely were not allowed to use ContainsKey then you could use the .Except extension.  But then you would have to write a custom comparer so don't do this :)

Comment: @GeneS That wouldn't be removing keys from the dictionary though; at best it would be creating a new dictionary with all of the keys in dict1 that aren't in dict2

Comment: @Servy.  Very true, By pointing out how to do it using Linq I was hoping to show that Linq is not the answer to everything and it definitely is not the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this would be:

```
foreach(var key in dic2.Keys)
{
    dic1.Remove(key);
}
```

LINQ stands for Language Integrated ***Query***.  It is for performing **queries** on data.  Queries do not mutate the underlying structures.  Since what you want to do is to mutate one of the queries LINQ is not an appropriate tool.

Also note that `Remove` returns a boolean indicating whether or not it actually removed the key.  It doesn't throw an exception.  You don't need to call `ContainsKey` before calling remove (this will save you an extra table lookup for each item).

Answer (score 1):

Linq is also using loops. Linq can just help you to find what you want to remove.

```
foreach (var kv in dict2.Where(kv => dict1.ContainsKey(kv.Key))) 
    dict1.Remove(kv.Key);
```

This should be efficient since it uses [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4) which is a O(1) operation, for every `KeyValuePair` in the second `Dictionary`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx

**Edit**: Of course Servy's approach is better in general because you can use `Dictionary.Remove` even if the given key does not exist.

Comment: The entire LINQ query is pointless.  There's no reason to not just loop over all of the keys in dict2.  It's actually *less* efficient because of the use of `ContainsKey`, not more efficient.

Comment: @Servy: Isn't this the same as what you say _"just loop over all of the keys in dict2"_? The query loops over _all_ pairs in dict2 and uses `ContainsKey` to check if the key is also in dict1. My point was that Linq doesn't help much here. But i've provided a way to use Linq anyway that doesn't hurt. **Edit** Now i've understood, you can use `Remove` even if the key doesn't exist. Point taken.

Comment: It's not *wrong* in that it won't break.  It's not not *helping*.  It's doing redundant work that `Remove` is already doing for you, so it's both less efficient at runntime and more code (and thus more to understand or misunderstand).

Answer (score -2):

As others mentioned, whether linq is the right tool for this job is debatable. However, if it has to be linq, I believe this is the apropriate solution:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int,double>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<int,double>();

dict1 = dict1.Where(kv => !dict2.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
             .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv=>kv.Value);
```

This does not remove the keys from the existing dictionary, instead it generates a new dictionary with only the required keys.

This might actually be faster if most of the keys have to be removed.

p.s.
[image]

Comment: As to the performance note, it will almost never be faster.  You're calling `ContainsKey` on every key in dict2, which is almost as much work as just calling `Remove`.  It needs to perform the table lookup in both cases, and unless there is a *really* bad hashing algorithm for the key, there won't be many items in each bucket so actually removing the item once it's been found ought to be quite fast.  While this could maybe possibly be faster, it would only be in rare edge cases.  The vast majority of the time it will be slower.

Comment: True, the performance will most likely be worse. Well, the only other excuse for using Linq here I can think of would be that you need less locking in a multi-thread scenario if you only modify the dictionary in this way.

Comment: Clearly the OP is trying to learn about LINQ.  Rather than trying to force a LINQ based solution onto a problem that clearly is not designed to be LINQ based, it will help them learn more to simply tell them that this is an inappropriate place to use LINQ.  Providing examples of LINQ that are really contrary to it's purpose/design is only being detrimental to their learning process.

Comment: I disagree strongly there. To judge whether a tool is appropriate for a given problem (and most importantly *why*), it clearly helps to know how solutions using that tool would work. Give the people the means to test and judge for themselves, no need to be condescending to them.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate the power and usefulness of LINQ then you should find a problem for which LINQ is an appropriate solution; then you can demonstrate correct use of it.  Using it incorrectly, is more likely to encourage future mis-use.

Comment: And if you want to demonstrate the risks and drawbacks of linq, then find a problem for which it is inappropriate, and demonstrate *that*. Future misuse is best prevented with full disclosure, not by withholding information for fear it might be used inappropriately

Comment: As you can see from my answer, I didn't just ignore the fact that he wanted a LINQ solution.  I described, without actually providing a LINQ solution, that it is not appropriate and explained *why* it's not appropriate for this particular application.  You simply provided a LINQ based solution and then later edited in "but don't do this" when I pointed out in comments that this isn't a good idea.  You neither state what *should* be done, nor why LINQ isn't a good solution.  If you did both of those, then also including a LINQ solution would be at least less harmful.

Comment: I clearly did *not* edit in "but don't do this" or anything like it, and my warning has been the first sentence of this answer from the start. Why say things that plainly are not true? I provided a proper Linq solution with caveats as supplement and comparison to the existing answers, and claiming that this is somehow harmful is really belittling the asker.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16430/discussion-between-hugorune-and-servy)