# Remove some object in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have variable like this :

```
var jsonResponse = (Dictionary<string,object>) _javaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(_dataExcel[ i ].DataBefore);
```

and items in jsonResponse like this :
[image]

i want remove list of object in keys MainView with HiddenName contains S#ID like this :
[image]

so value at index 3 will be removed, any idea ? thanks for helping :)

my question is to remove some element in list of object in dictionary not remove at all element in dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to remove items from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320289/efficient-way-to-remove-items-from-dictionary)

Comment: @SehaxX: this is not his direct problem its not just about deleting here. the trick is to reach the item to be deleted

Comment: @SehaxX, in that case, that delete all value, if my case not delete all value, just some specific value in list of object

Comment: @RudiEncok, The accepted answer of the linked duplicate does not have a `if` to filter, you can add one.

Comment: @RudiEncok : did you try to cast the value instead of object to Dictionary<string,object> and then check on each key value if contains S#ID

Comment: @HanyHabib it's getting error, because i parsed json object with javascriptserializer to dictionary

Comment: @RudiEncok: what error your are getting ?

Comment: @HanyHabib, Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]]'. that error if i change object to list<object>, list<string> etc.

Comment: Your question is wrong. You don't remove anything from Dictinary. You try to remove an item from an object that is in the Dictionary. So first isolate your object get it by key "MainView". Now if your object is a list you can remove an item from list.

Comment: Do you know the dictionary is in the MainView and not the SubViews? SubView is shown to contain a dictionary also.